# Global variables across modules

Tags: c, global-variables, d, dmd

OK, so this is the concept :

I'm currently writing a fairly complex project, consisting of 10's of different modules and classes.

I need to have one basic set of variables/options (an associative array?) which will be shared (read/write) by all modules (or selected ones) at any time.

What would be the most D-friendly way to achieve this?

---

**UPDATE:**

Hmm... just created a variable definition in one module (let's say `globals.d` module) and no matter where I import it, I can always get/set it. That simple?! (Or am I missing anything?)

Comment: That sounds fine!  It's hard to say without more specifics, so I hesitate to write an answer.  An associative array declared at module scope should be just fine for some configuration options that can be introduced dynamically.  You may want to look at std.variant if you need to have mixed types in the same container.  If multiple threads will access this/these variable(s), then you'll want to declare it/them as `shared`.  If it will be mutated after multiple threads are spawned, then you will probably need to do something more complicated to ensure that it doesn't go stale in some threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just filling this in so there's an answer: yes, you generally would want to make a new module like globals.d and simply import it from all the other modules that use it.